# Tortoise SVN - Unable to connect to a repository at URL ' ', An error occurred during SSL communication

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed Tortoise SVN client software in my Windows 10 PC, it was working for almost 10 months very well. And just one week before a problem occurred to it. When i was trying to checkout, it is showing the message -  Unable to connect to a repository at URL ' ', An error occurred during SSL communication.

We uninstalled and deleted C:\users\user\Appdata contents. 
And uninstalled all antivirus and all newly installed softwares. But the problem is not solved.

It seems the problem is in basic communication of the system with the server.
In this wireshark capture - 192.168.2.3 is the server ip address and 192.168.2.150

The wireshark capture for the communication is attached

> 767 25.716025      192.168.2.150         224.0.0.252           LLMNR
>   72     Standard query 0x3f09 A laxvenserver
>
> 768 25.716081      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         NBNS
>   116    Name query response NB 192.168.2.3
>
> 769 25.716364      fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef ff02::1:ff51:e85b
>   ICMPv6   86     Neighbor Solicitation for fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b
>   from 40:f2:e9:d4:de:ad
>
> 770 25.716428      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         LLMNR
>   100    Standard query response 0x3f09 A laxvenserver A 192.168.2.3
>
> 771 25.716499      fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>   ICMPv6   86     Neighbor Advertisement
>
> 772 25.716586      192.168.2.150         224.0.0.252           LLMNR
>   72     Standard query 0x9173 AAAA laxvenserver
>
> 773 25.716725      fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b
>   LLMNR    120    Standard query response 0x3f09 A laxvenserver A
>   192.168.2.3
>
> 774 25.716770      fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>   ICMPv6   168    Destination Unreachable (Port unreachable)
>
> 775 25.716816      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         LLMNR
>   112    Standard query response 0x9173 AAAA laxvenserver AAAA
>   fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>
> 776 25.718586      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   66     51195 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256
>   SACK_PERM=1
>
> 777 25.718923      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   66     443 → 51195 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460
>   WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
>
> 778 25.751045      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TLSv1.2
>   571    Client Hello
>
> 779 25.754341      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   1295   Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello
>   Done
>
> 780 25.756659      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TLSv1.2
>   180    Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake
>   Message
>
> 781 25.757393      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   328    New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake
>   Message
>
> 782 25.757819      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51195 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=644 Ack=1516 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 783 25.758108      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51195 [ACK] Seq=1516 Ack=645 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 784 25.758109      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   85     Encrypted Alert
>
> 785 25.758180      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51195 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1547 Ack=645 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 786 25.758230      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51195 → 443 [ACK] Seq=645 Ack=1547 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 787 25.758496      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51195 → 443 [ACK] Seq=645 Ack=1548 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 788 25.786368      52.114.32.7           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51158 [ACK] Seq=428 Ack=9395 Win=1026 Len=0
>
> 789 25.786641      52.114.32.7           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   481    Application Data
>
> 790 25.822569      fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b ff02::1:3
>   LLMNR    92     Standard query 0xdc13 A laxvenserver
>
> 791 25.822673      192.168.2.150         224.0.0.252           LLMNR
>   72     Standard query 0xdc13 A laxvenserver
>
> 792 25.822846      fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b ff02::1:3
>   LLMNR    92     Standard query 0xde86 AAAA laxvenserver
>
> 793 25.822881      fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b
>   LLMNR    120    Standard query response 0xdc13 A laxvenserver A
>   192.168.2.3
>
> 794 25.822991      192.168.2.150         224.0.0.252           LLMNR
>   72     Standard query 0xde86 AAAA laxvenserver
>
> 795 25.823054      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         LLMNR
>   100    Standard query response 0xdc13 A laxvenserver A 192.168.2.3
>
> 796 25.823120      fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b
>   LLMNR    132    Standard query response 0xde86 AAAA laxvenserver AAAA
>   fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>
> 797 25.823183      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         LLMNR
>   112    Standard query response 0xde86 AAAA laxvenserver AAAA
>   fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>
> 798 25.824038      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   66     51196 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256
>   SACK_PERM=1
>
> 799 25.824213      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   66     443 → 51196 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460
>   WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
>
> 800 25.836777      192.168.2.150         52.114.32.7           TCP
>   54     51158 → 443 [ACK] Seq=9395 Ack=855 Win=253 Len=0
>
> 801 25.855912      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TLSv1.2
>   571    Client Hello
>
> 802 25.859043      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   1295   Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello
>   Done
>
> 803 25.861489      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TLSv1.2
>   180    Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake
>   Message
>
> 804 25.862211      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   328    New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake
>   Message
>
> 805 25.862540      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51196 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=644 Ack=1516 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 806 25.862782      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51196 [ACK] Seq=1516 Ack=645 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 807 25.862832      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   85     Encrypted Alert
>
> 808 25.862880      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51196 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1547 Ack=645 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 809 25.862930      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51196 → 443 [ACK] Seq=645 Ack=1547 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 810 25.863232      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51196 → 443 [ACK] Seq=645 Ack=1548 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 811 25.864329      fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b ff02::1:3
>   LLMNR    92     Standard query 0xe47e A laxvenserver
>
> 812 25.864442      192.168.2.150         224.0.0.252           LLMNR
>   72     Standard query 0xe47e A laxvenserver
>
> 813 25.864641      fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b
>   LLMNR    120    Standard query response 0xe47e A laxvenserver A
>   192.168.2.3
>
> 814 25.864655      fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b ff02::1:3
>   LLMNR    92     Standard query 0x3927 AAAA laxvenserver
>
> 815 25.864732      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         LLMNR
>   100    Standard query response 0xe47e A laxvenserver A 192.168.2.3
>
> 816 25.864791      192.168.2.150         224.0.0.252           LLMNR
>   72     Standard query 0x3927 AAAA laxvenserver
>
> 817 25.864963      fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef fe80::a480:ad01:7851:e85b
>   LLMNR    132    Standard query response 0x3927 AAAA laxvenserver AAAA
>   fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>
> 818 25.865055      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         LLMNR
>   112    Standard query response 0x3927 AAAA laxvenserver AAAA
>   fe80::c14d:c9b7:7fc1:62ef
>
> 819 25.865818      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   66     51197 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256
>   SACK_PERM=1
>
> 820 25.865987      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   66     443 → 51197 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460
>   WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
>
> 821 25.897956      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TLSv1.2
>   571    Client Hello
>
> 822 25.901043      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   1295   Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello
>   Done
>
> 823 25.903281      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TLSv1.2
>   180    Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake
>   Message
>
> 824 25.903961      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   328    New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake
>   Message
>
> 825 25.904363      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51197 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=644 Ack=1516 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 826 25.904612      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51197 [ACK] Seq=1516 Ack=645 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 827 25.904662      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TLSv1.2
>   85     Encrypted Alert
>
> 828 25.904711      192.168.2.3           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     443 → 51197 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1547 Ack=645 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 829 25.904762      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51197 → 443 [ACK] Seq=645 Ack=1547 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 830 25.905117      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.3           TCP
>   54     51197 → 443 [ACK] Seq=645 Ack=1548 Win=65536 Len=0
>
> 831 26.385164      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.2           SMB
>   93     Tree Disconnect Request
>
> 832 26.385371      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.2           SMB
>   97     Logoff AndX Request
>
> 833 26.386701      192.168.2.2           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     139 → 51182 [ACK] Seq=1216 Ack=1008 Win=64512 Len=0
>
> 834 26.386772      192.168.2.2           192.168.2.150         SMB
>   93     Tree Disconnect Response
>
> 835 26.386950      192.168.2.2           192.168.2.150         SMB
>   97     Logoff AndX Response
>
> 836 26.387016      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.2           TCP
>   54     51182 → 139 [ACK] Seq=1008 Ack=1298 Win=64256 Len=0
>
> 837 26.387393      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.2           TCP
>   54     51182 → 139 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1008 Ack=1298 Win=64256 Len=0
>
> 838 26.388827      192.168.2.2           192.168.2.150         TCP
>   60     139 → 51182 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1298 Ack=1009 Win=64512 Len=0
>
> 839 26.389056      192.168.2.150         192.168.2.2           TCP
>   54     51182 → 139 [ACK] Seq=1009 Ack=1299 Win=64256 Len=0
>
> 840 26.926330      Cisco_20:f3:14
>   Spanning-tree-(for-bridges)_00 STP      60     RST. Root =
>   32768/0/00:8e: 73:20:f2:fb  Cost = 0  Port = 0x8019

Suggesting a solution  for this problem shall be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi all, Regarding this problem, there is a progress. We faced this problem in two systems. In one of the system the problem is solved. In this, today at bootup, a pop up message appears and in this message, the tab "Accept Certificate Permanently" is clicked. After that Tortoise Login window appeared. When the user id and passwords given, tortoise svn is nicely checkout and it is properly working now.

Comment: But in other system the problem remains. Because we don't how to make this solution window  popup. Tortoise experts, please help